# Using .net reflection to find a common ancestor class

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an assembly containing types that have a common ancestor class (defined within the assembly. The common ancestor is in most cases *not* the class's immediate base type.

I need to be able to filter out, from all the types in this assembly, those with this common ancestor. For various reasons I can't instantiate the types (they do not as a rule have a common constructor signature) so I have to start with `myAssembly.GetTypes()` and examine the properties of the types themselves. In other words I have to work with classes, not instances of the classes.

How do I examine each Type in this collection to find if it inherits from the desired common ancestor or not?

Later: no worries, I have it now. The trick is to instantiate a type object that is the ancestor type *from the assembly*, eg

```
Type ancestor = assy.getType("myAncestorClassName", true, true);
Type[] interestingClasses = assy.GetTYypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(ancestor));
```

However this will not work:

```
Type[] interestingClasses = assy.GetTYypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AncestorClass)));
```

because, I think, the ancestor type is defined in the other assembly and not in the main assembly.

Much, much later....Thanks to everyone who contributed answers to this. I was diverted to something else along the way, but I now have a neat solution (and have learned something new).

Comment: you just build a tree of Types linked via their direct BaseType which itself is a Type again... at the root there is only one node - it is the Type `object` from all and everything inherits...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each type in your collection, you can see if they derive from this ancestor by using [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx).

For example:

```
var types = assembly.GetTypes().Exclude(t => typeof(CommonAncestor).IsAssignableFrom(t));
```

This should get all types in the assembly which aren't derived from `CommonAncestor`.

Comment: Thanks - the problem I overlooked is that the type in question must be 'extracted'from the loaded assembly. I was referencing it directly (from the referenced assembly) and that does not work.

Comment: It should still work, as `typeof(AncestorClass)` will be the type from whatever assembly it was loaded from. Are you sure you were using the correct definition of `AncestorClass` from the correct assembly?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) to find out if one type is assignable from an instance of another type.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using C#

```
Type[] types = myAssenbly.GetTypes();

foreach(Type t in types)
{
    // Is a Common Ancestor subclass
    bool isString = t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CommonAncestor));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this snippet:

```
var commonAncestor = typeof(object);
var descendants =
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(
    type => commonAncestor.IsAssignableFrom(type));
```

This will fetch all types in the current assembly that are descended from `object`. Naturally, replace it with your own common ancestor type.

The `Type.IsAssignableFrom()` method checks if you can do something like:

```
MyType b = new MyType();
object a = b;
```

without errors.